# Dynamically created textboxes and changes plus jQuery in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering how to read off a value from a textbox that resides in a partialview and output the value into a textbox within the initial window.

Here's my code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    // Calculate the sum when the document has been loaded.
    var total = 0;
    $("#fieldValues :input.fieldKronor").each(function (e) {
        total += Number($(this).val());
    });

    // Set the value to the correspondent textbox
    $("#fieldSummation").text(total);

    // Re-calculate on change
    $("#fieldValues :input.fieldKronor").change(function (e) {
        var total = 0;
        $("#fieldValues :input.fieldKronor").each(function (e) {
            total += Number($(this).val());
        });

        $("#fieldSummation").text(total);

    });
}); </script>
```

Here's the table where in info is...

```
<table id="fieldValues" style="width: 60%; margin-bottom: 2em">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Rubrik, t.ex. teknik*</th>
                    <th>Kronor (ange endast siffror)*</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlStaffRows" runat="server"></asp:Panel>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Total kostnad</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="" class="fieldSummation" style="width:120px" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
```

And here's the partialview...

```
<tr>
    <td class="greyboxchildsocialsecuritynumberheading4" style="padding-bottom:1em">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRubrikBox" ToolTip="Rubrik" runat="server" Width="120"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td class="greyboxchildnameheading3" style="padding-bottom:1em">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtKronorBox" class="fieldKronor" ToolTip="Kronor" runat="server" Width="120"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>               
</tr>
```

Comment: is this partial view rendered through your view ?

Comment: Your code should work fine.  Is there a question?

Comment: Well when I run my code, nothin happens.
No input is entered to the textbox called fieldSummation....

Comment: Mahesh, the partial-view is called thru the code-behind. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line needs a change in both places:

```
$("#fieldSummation").text(total);
```

To this:

```
$(".fieldSummation").val(total);
```

To match this:

```
<input type="text" value="" class="fieldSummation" style="width:120px" />
```

You need `.fieldSummation` [with the `.` prefix because it's a class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/), not an ID.
Alternatively, change the input to `id="fieldSummation"` instead and leave`#fieldSummation` there.

Also, because it's an input, use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the value, a normal element uses `.text()`, but an input needs `.val()` to set it's `value=""` attribute.

You can also reduce the overall code here with a function, [here's an example with the above problems fixed and DRY coded](http://jsfiddle.net/uTgK4/).

Comment: Thank you!
I found the error to that the project wasn't referencing the jQuery file properly.

Thanks again for the help!